# Noun meaning loud noise or flash used as symbol of apocalypse

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word  often used to describe ritualistic work that means, as I remember it, "a loud noise or flash used as a symbol of the apocalypse"?

I remember the word being something like an iconoclast,  but it is clearly not that word.

Comment: I can't remember it well but the instrument was called 'Sur' I think and will be used by the angel Israfel.

Comment: Since it's a trumpet, I guess it would be "toot".

Comment: Symbolic not Literal

Comment: See if anything in this story is what you are targeting: http://www.newyorker.com/tech/elements/the-first-light-of-the-trinity-atomic-test

Comment: Were you thinking of cataclysmic?

Answer (score 2):

Israfel will play **a trumpet**. The sound of a trumpet can be referred to as **taratantara**
From the Qur'an:

> - And the trumpet shall be blown, so all those that are in the heavens and all those that are in the earth shall swoon, except him whom Allah will ; then it shall be blown again, then they shall stand up awaiting." —Qur'an (39.68).  [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israfil)

As for the sound from that instrument, The Free Dictionary, mentions [**"taratantara"**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trumpet) as the sound of a bugle or trumpet.

Comment: The term I'm looking for is the representative sound not the literal sound

Comment: I think it's more commonly referred to as just 'tantara'.  But good word, the MW unabridged lists 'taratantara'